# Passing array by reference to extension methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

How to pass an array to a extension method by reference.

this is what i have tried but not working.

```
public static void RemoveAtIndex(ref this int[] arr, int index)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't send extension's target object by ref.
Do you relly need it?
Is array replaced by the new one by the extension method?

Answer (score -1):

Linq is used to return data, not to change data. With a little different approach you **replace** the complete array and not changing the array.

First add this little extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
    {
        return source.Where((it, i) => i != index);
    }
}
```

Then you could do it the "Linq way":

```
var a = new[] {1,2,3};
a = a.SkipAt(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Linq !== Extension methods